# How to throw a custom error in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm wanting to throw an error when reference keys are missing, however instead of failing through a integrity check, I want to list out the missing keys. I've created the below which works. However I'm hoping there is a way to optimise it and reduce the number of lines of code.

```
DECLARE @NonRefKeys INT

SELECT @NonRefKeys = SUM(1)
FROM staging.Sale sa
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT cu.Customer_Shipping_ID
    FROM staging.Customer cu
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(sa.Customer_Shipping_ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(cu.Customer_Shipping_ID)))

IF @NonRefKeys IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Missing_Ref') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Missing_Ref;

SELECT sa.Customer_Shipping_ID AS ID
INTO #Missing_Ref
FROM staging.Sale sa
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT cu.Customer_Shipping_ID
        FROM staging.Customer cu
        WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(sa.Customer_Shipping_ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(cu.Customer_Shipping_ID)))

DECLARE @Current_ID VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Missing_ID VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @Output_Error VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE id_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID
FROM #Missing_Ref;

OPEN id_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor INTO @Current_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF (@Missing_ID != '')
        SET @Missing_ID = @Missing_ID + ', ';

    SET @Missing_ID = @Missing_ID + @Current_ID;

    FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor INTO @Current_ID
END
CLOSE id_cursor
DEALLOCATE id_cursor

SET @Output_Error = 'ERROR: Key/s ' + @Missing_ID + ' for Customer Shipping ID missing from Customer table';

RAISERROR (@Output_Error,16,1)
END
```

Comment: This really belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but just reducing the number of lines of code is not an optimization. Because we spend far more time reading code than writing it, the priority should always be to have clear, readable, maintainable code that works correctly and performs acceptably. How many lines of code there are should not be a consideration at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out... you can update a variable without having to create a temp table

There is a trailing "," that you have to remove.

```
Declare @MissingIDList VarChar (Max) = ''

DROP Table #MyTableOfMissingIds

Select *
Into #MyTableOfMissingIds
From 
(   Select 1 MissingId
    Union Select 2
    Union Select 3
    Union Select 4
    Union Select 5
    Union Select 6
) xx

Update #MyTableOfMissingIds
Set @MissingIDList = @MissingIDList + Cast (MissingId as VarChar) + ','

Declare @Output_Error VarChar (Max)
SET @Output_Error = 'ERROR: Key/s ' + @MissingIDList + ' for Customer Shipping ID missing from Customer table';

RAISERROR (@Output_Error,16,1)
```

The `Update` statement in my example can be replaced with one of your tables like this (OTTOMH, so syntax may need to be verified)

```
Declare @MissingIDList VarChar (Max) = ''
Declare @Output_Error VarChar (Max)

UPDATE staging.Sale SET 
Set @MissingIDList = @MissingIDList + Cast (Customer_Shipping_ID as VarChar) + ','
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT cu.Customer_Shipping_ID
        FROM staging.Customer cu
        WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(sa.Customer_Shipping_ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(cu.Customer_Shipping_ID)))

SET @Output_Error = 'ERROR: Key/s ' + @MissingIDList + ' for Customer Shipping ID missing from Customer table';

RAISERROR (@Output_Error,16,1)
```

Now, if you're good with using XML, here is another cool method:

```
Declare @MissingIDList VarChar (Max) = ''
Declare @Output_Error VarChar (Max)

DROP Table #MyTableOfMissingIds

Select *
Into #MyTableOfMissingIds
From 
(   Select 1 MissingId
    Union Select 2
    Union Select 3
    Union Select 4
    Union Select 5
    Union Select 6
) xx

SELECT @MissingIDList = 
    SUBSTRING(
                (   SELECT ',' + Cast (MissingId as VarChar)
                    FROM #MyTableOfMissingIds s
                    ORDER BY 1
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                )
                ,2,200000
            )

SET @Output_Error = 'ERROR: Key/s ' + @MissingIDList + ' for Customer Shipping ID missing from Customer table';

RAISERROR (@Output_Error,16,1)
```

Comment: The update is on #MyTableOfMissingIds, however you set @MissingIDList. I ran it, and it works, although makes little sense. :S

Comment: @stats101, #MyTableOfMissingIds is the source.  When you do an update with a where clause, all the rows are used as a source, and as a destination, along with any variables used.  The trick is to update the variable @MissingIDList, and since the update goes row by row, you get a concatenation effect, because you have set it to `@MissingIDList = @MissingIDList + MissingIdColumn + ','`.